# Why is the body not expanding with inside element?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

As shown below, the body has divs which have floating elements, but they are all cleared.

**The Code (https://jsfiddle.net/4ke0cxg7/2/):**

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  background: grey;
}
#foot {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  background: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
#h {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
#wrapper {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span9">
          <div class="card card-small">
            <div class="card-heading simple">
              Phone Book
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
              <!-- I have other tabs here --> 
              <div class="tab-content">
                <div class="active tab-pane" id="columns">
                  <table class="table table-striped table-condensed sampleTable">
                    <thead>
                      <tr>
                        <th>&nbsp;</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>State</th>
                        <th>Phone</th>
                      </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>

                      <tr>
                        <td>0</td>
                        <td title="Scroll to the column">
                          <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-row-selector="true" class="column-selector">John</a>
                        </td>
                        <td>NY</td>
                        <td></td>
                      </tr>

                      <!-- Snipped for conciseness -->

                      <tr>
                        <td>21</td>
                        <td title="Scroll to the column">
                          <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-row-selector="true" class="column-selector">Rambo</a>
                        </td>
                        <td>NY</td>
                        <td></td>
                      </tr>

                    </tbody>
                  </table>
                </div>

              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="foot">
    Footer
  </div>
</body>
```

The footer hangs in middle of the page. Why does not body expand to contain the `#wrapper` div?

**UPDATE:** I can change any style except footer(it's controlled by other guys). Why does body not expand to contain the div?

Comment: replace `position:absolute;` with `position:relative`: https://jsfiddle.net/4ke0cxg7/3/ ??

Comment: I don't see the problem but you can't fix a CSS issue if you don't have control over the CSS.

Comment: @Rob - Do you not see the problem on jsFiddle? The footer sticks to window's bottom instead of page. Try reducing the vertical size of preview pane... https://jsfiddle.net/4ke0cxg7/4/

Comment: And I can change any style except the footer element.

Comment: It would be great if you could accept an answer, if any, that solve your question, or let us know what is missing, so we can find one that does

Answer (score 0):

Change your CSS like this

```
html {
  overflow: auto;
  height: 100vh;
}
body {
  position: relative;
  background: grey;
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/LGSon/4ke0cxg7/5/)

```css
html {
  overflow: auto;
  height: 100vh;
}
body {
  position: relative;
  background: grey;
  min-height: 100%;
}
#foot {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  background: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
#h {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
#wrapper {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://s3-sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/vochani/bootplus.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span9">
          <div class="card card-small">
            <div class="card-heading simple">
              Heading
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
              <div class="tab-content">
                <div class="active tab-pane" id="columns">
                  <table class="table table-striped table-condensed sampleTable">
                    <thead>
                      <tr>
                        <th>&nbsp;</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>State</th>
                        <th>Phone</th>
                      </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>

                      <tr>
                        <td>0</td>
                        <td title="Scroll to the column">
                          <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-row-selector="true" class="column-selector">John</a>
                        </td>
                        <td>NY</td>
                        <td></td>
                      </tr>

                      <tr>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td title="Scroll to the column">
                          <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-row-selector="true" class="column-selector">Kavita</a>
                        </td>
                        <td>NY</td>
                        <td></td>
                      </tr>

                      <tr>
                        <td>2</td>
                        <td title="Scroll to the column">
                          <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-row-selector="true" class="column-selector">Luke</a>
                        </td>
                        <td>NY</td>
                        <td></td>
                      </tr>

                      <tr>
                        <td>2</td>
                        <td title="Scroll to the column">
                          <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-row-selector="true" class="column-selector">Luke</a>
                        </td>
                        <td>NY</td>
                        <td></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td>2</td>
                        <td title="Scroll to the column">
                          <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-row-selector="true" class="column-selector">Luke</a>
                        </td>
                        <td>NY</td>
                        <td></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td>2</td>
                        <td title="Scroll to the column">
                          <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-row-selector="true" class="column-selector">Luke</a>
                        </td>
                        <td>NY</td>
                        <td></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td>2</td>
                        <td title="Scroll to the column">
                          <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-row-selector="true" class="column-selector">Luke</a>
                        </td>
                        <td>NY</td>
                        <td></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td>2</td>
                        <td title="Scroll to the column">
                          <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-row-selector="true" class="column-selector">Luke</a>
                        </td>
                        <td>NY</td>
                        <td></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td>2</td>
                        <td title="Scroll to the column">
                          <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-row-selector="true" class="column-selector">Luke</a>
                        </td>
                        <td>NY</td>
                        <td></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td>3</td>
                        <td title="Scroll to the column">
                          <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-row-selector="true" class="column-selector">Bob</a>
                        </td>
                        <td>NY</td>
                        <td></td>
                      </tr>

                      <tr>
                        <td>4</td>
                        <td title="Scroll to the column">
                          <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-row-selector="true" class="column-selector">Peter</a>
                        </td>
                        <td>WA</td>
                        <td></td>
                      </tr>

                      <tr>
                        <td>5</td>
                        <td title="Scroll to the column">
                          <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-row-selector="true" class="column-selector">Mike</a>
                        </td>
                        <td>CA</td>
                        <td></td>
                      </tr>

                      <tr>
                        <td>6</td>
                        <td title="Scroll to the column">
                          <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-row-selector="true" class="column-selector">Andrew</a>
                        </td>
                        <td>CA</td>
                        <td></td>
                      </tr>

                      <tr>
                        <td>7</td>
                        <td title="Scroll to the column">
                          <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-row-selector="true" class="column-selector">Hilo</a>
                        </td>
                        <td>CA</td>
                        <td></td>
                      </tr>

                      <tr>
                        <td>8</td>
                        <td title="Scroll to the column">
                          <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-row-selector="true" class="column-selector">Jeff</a>
                        </td>
                        <td>CA</td>
                        <td></td>
                      </tr>

                      <tr>
                        <td>9</td>
                        <td title="Scroll to the column">
                          <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-row-selector="true" class="column-selector">Elon</a>
                        </td>
                        <td>WA</td>
                        <td></td>
                      </tr>

                      <tr>
                        <td>10</td>
                        <td title="Scroll to the column">
                          <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-row-selector="true" class="column-selector">Cindy</a>
                        </td>
                        <td>CA</td>
                        <td></td>
                      </tr>

                      <tr>
                        <td>11</td>
                        <td title="Scroll to the column">
                          <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-row-selector="true" class="column-selector">Bri</a>
                        </td>
                        <td>CA</td>
                        <td></td>
                      </tr>

                      <tr>
                        <td>12</td>
                        <td title="Scroll to the column">
                          <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-row-selector="true" class="column-selector">Brian</a>
                        </td>
                        <td>CA</td>
                        <td></td>
                      </tr>

                      <tr>
                        <td>13</td>
                        <td title="Scroll to the column">
                          <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-row-selector="true" class="column-selector">NIck</a>
                        </td>
                        <td>CA</td>
                        <td></td>
                      </tr>

                      <tr>
                        <td>14</td>
                        <td title="Scroll to the column">
                          <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-row-selector="true" class="column-selector">Miranda</a>
                        </td>
                        <td>CA</td>
                        <td></td>
                      </tr>

                      <tr>
                        <td>15</td>
                        <td title="Scroll to the column">
                          <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-row-selector="true" class="column-selector">Lauren</a>
                        </td>
                        <td>CA</td>
                        <td></td>
                      </tr>

                      <tr>
                        <td>16</td>
                        <td title="Scroll to the column">
                          <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-row-selector="true" class="column-selector">Cherry</a>
                        </td>
                        <td>CA</td>
                        <td></td>
                      </tr>

                      <tr>
                        <td>17</td>
                        <td title="Scroll to the column">
                          <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-row-selector="true" class="column-selector">Jessica</a>
                        </td>
                        <td>CA</td>
                        <td></td>
                      </tr>

                      <tr>
                        <td>18</td>
                        <td title="Scroll to the column">
                          <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-row-selector="true" class="column-selector">Bom</a>
                        </td>
                        <td>CA</td>
                        <td></td>
                      </tr>

                      <tr>
                        <td>19</td>
                        <td title="Scroll to the column">
                          <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-row-selector="true" class="column-selector">Ram</a>
                        </td>
                        <td>NY</td>
                        <td></td>
                      </tr>

                      <tr>
                        <td>20</td>
                        <td title="Scroll to the column">
                          <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-row-selector="true" class="column-selector">Telco</a>
                        </td>
                        <td>WA</td>
                        <td></td>
                      </tr>

                      <tr>
                        <td>21</td>
                        <td title="Scroll to the column">
                          <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-row-selector="true" class="column-selector">Rambo</a>
                        </td>
                        <td>NY</td>
                        <td></td>
                      </tr>

                    </tbody>
                  </table>
                </div>

              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="foot">
    Footer
  </div>
```